# S3 Versioning and Lifecycle rules - Will "Expire current versions of objects" also delete the delete markers?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am having trouble understanding the relationship between Delete markers and Lifecycle rules in S3 with versioning.

**Here is my lifecycle rule:**

[image]

[image]

Does this mean that the **Expire current versions of objects** option would delete a delete marker after it becomes the "current" version? AKA 180 days after the actual current version is deleted?

From what I understand this would mean:

- After 180 days the current version of **example.txt** would expire, a delete marker is created for it and the current version becomes a noncurrent version attached to the delete marker
- Another 180 days later, the noncurrent **example.txt** would be permanently deleted and the "current" version (the delete marker) would "expire", and since it is a delete marker that means it would be permanently deleted as well

Is this an accurate understanding or do I need to make an additional lifecycle rule that deletes expired delete markers?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct

- Delete marker on current version makes it non current version
- After another 180 days, since you are deleting non current version it will Alsop delete delete markers of non current version too.

> An expired object delete marker is removed if all noncurrent versions of an object expire after deleting a versioned object.

That is why you cannot expire current version and delete expire object markers together.

Refer [Removing expired object delete markers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/lifecycle-configuration-examples.html#lifecycle-config-conceptual-ex7) , and [understanding delete markers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/ManagingDelMarkers.html) for more detail

Answer (score 1):

I realize this question has technically been answered, but can I get some clarification? The S3 documents around this are inscrutable.

Following along with the OP and adding my own notes:

Starting with the versioned object like so:

```
example.txt 
 1. (current version) - example.txt v2
 2. (noncurrent version) - example.txt v1
```

After 180 days the current version of example.txt would expire, a delete marker is created for it and the current version becomes a noncurrent version. At this point it looks like so:

```
example.txt 
 1. (current version) - delete marker
 2. (noncurrent version) - example.txt v2
 3. (noncurrent version) - example.txt v1
```

Another 180 days later, the noncurrent example.txt versions would be permanently deleted and the "current" version (the delete marker) would "expire". So now it looks like so.

```
example.txt 
 1. (current version) - expired delete marker
```

Now what happens?

One would think you would then add the **Delete expired object delete markers** action to clean the expired delete marker up. But no. S3 won't let you add that action.

**You cannot enable Delete expired object delete markers if you enable Expire current versions of objects.**

But it doesn't clearly explain why.

All I want to do is delete an object after a certain amount of days!